# How to keep fractions in your equation output

Tags: python, math, sympy, fractions, integral

I've been using Python to calculate math equations. For example:

```
from sympy import Symbol, Derivative, Integral
x = Symbol('x')
d = Symbol('d')
Integral(8*x**(6/5)-7*x**(3/2),x).doit()
```

Which results in the output:

```
3.63636363636364*x**2.2 - 2.8*x**2.5
```

Is there a way to show this answer as fractions as opposed to decimals? I would like to see the output as:

```
(40/11)*x**(11/5)-(14/5)*x**(5/2)+C
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

SymPy has Rational class for rational numbers.

```
from sympy import *
# other stuff 
integrate(8*x**Rational(6, 5) - 7*x**Rational(3, 2),x)
```

No need for `Integral().doit()` unless you actually want to print out the un-evaluated form.

Other versions:

```
integrate(8*x**Rational('6/5') - 7*x**Rational('3/2'),x)
```

(rational number can be parsed from a string);

```
integrate(8*x**(S.One*6/5) - 7*x**(S.One*3/2),x)
```

(beginning the computation with the SymPy object for "1" turns it into SymPy object manipulation, avoiding plain Python division, which would give a float)

Comment: Any idea on how we would use Rational on non-division problems such as `integrate((x+1)*math.e**((7*x**2)+(14*x)))`?

Comment: @d84_n1nj4 It's `integrate((x+1)*exp(7*x**2 + 14*x), x)`  - use the exponential function, not `e**` But if you really want to, there is `E` in SymPy: `integrate((x+1)*E**(7*x**2 + 14*x), x)` works too. The general thing is, plain Python constants are floating point numbers, which is not what you want. You want the corresponding SymPy objects, obtainable from SymPy directly.

Answer (score 7):

you can work with the [`fractions` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#module-fractions) in order to have integral fractions:

```
from sympy import Symbol, Derivative, Integral
from fractions import Fraction
x = Symbol('x')
d = Symbol('d')
ii = Integral(8*x**Fraction(6,5)-7*x**Fraction(3,2),x).doit()
# 40*x**(11/5)/11 - 14*x**(5/2)/5
```

there is also the [`Rational`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#rational) class in sympy itself:

```
from sympy import Symbol, Derivative, Integral, Rational
x = Symbol('x')
d = Symbol('d')
ii = Integral(8*x**Rational(6,5)-7*x**Rational(3,2),x).doit()
```

Answer (score 5):

Use sympy's `rational` instead of `6/5`. Python will immediately interpret `6/5` and return some floating point number (`1.2` in this case).

```
from sympy import Symbol, Derivative, Integral, Rational
x = Symbol('x')
d = Symbol('d')
Integral(8*x**(Rational(6,5))-7*x**(Rational(3,2)),x).doit()
```