# How to represent real number as fractions with sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I would like to if there is some way to represent something like 0.25 as 1/4 ?

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45651029/2476977). In short, you can get a "symbolic" 1/4 with `sympy.Rational(1,4)`.

Comment: If you want to find the fraction using the decimal number, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23344185/2476977)