# Loss of precision in calculations involving fractions and floating-point numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, sympy, fractions

```py
import sympy as sp
from fractions import Fraction

new_matrix_aux = [['X',   'B', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'U1', 'U2'], 
                  ['X2', 10/3,    0,    1,  2/3,  1/3, -2/3, -1/3,  2/3],  
                  ['X1',  4/3,    1,    0,  2/3, -2/3,  1/3,  2/3, -1/3]]

z_function = "Z = 1 * X1 + 2 * X2 + 3 * X3 + 0 * X4 + 0 * X5 + M * U1 + M * U2"


lista_de_operaciones_zj = []

for j in range(1, len(new_matrix_aux[0])):
    z = z_function
    for i in range(1, len(new_matrix_aux)):
        z = z.replace(new_matrix_aux[i][0], str(new_matrix_aux[i][j]))
    for k in range(1, len(new_matrix_aux[0])):
        z = z.replace(new_matrix_aux[0][k], '0')
    z = z.replace(z[0], z[0] + '_' + new_matrix_aux[0][j])
    lista_de_operaciones_zj.append(z)
    print(f'"{z}"')

variables, resultados = [], []

for operacion in lista_de_operaciones_zj:
    variable = operacion.split("Z_")[1].split(" = ")[0]
    variables.append(variable)
    expression = operacion.split("= ")[1]
    resultado = sp.sympify(expression)
    resultados.append(resultado)

output = [variables, resultados]
print(output)
```

This is the incorrect output that I am getting, where for some reason throughout the mathematical processes of the code the precision of the calculated values is lost (especially in those operations that involved fractions as can be seen below):

```py
[['B', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'U1', 'U2'], [8.0000000000000003, 1, 2, 2.000000000000000, 0, -0.9999999999999999, 0, 0.9999999999999999]]
```

This should be the correct output matrix where there was no loss of precision during the calculations.

```py
[['B', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'U1', 'U2'], [8, 1, 2, 2, 0, -1, 0, 1]]
```

I assume this problem is due to the nature of floating-point calculations in Python. Floating point numbers are internally represented in binary and can introduce small rounding errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) There is probably also a Python duplicate, just search the site.

Comment: @OcasoProtal mmm... Sorry, I'm afraid the question you're quoting doesn't answer my current question. Here you are doing operations with fractions and using sympy for the resolutions

Comment: @Stef I don't understand what I should modify in my code?

Comment: Your code is *not* doing operations with fractions -- the question about floating point math explains what you are seeing. Use `Fraction(2,3)` if you want to use the fraction `2/3`.

Comment: @JohnColeman I know, but the problem is that I don't know exactly where I should put it to perform operations with fractions. I have modified my code several times the truth is that I am somewhat lost with this problem

Comment: Perhaps you could forget your code for a bit and first get comfortable using the `fractions` module. Figure out how to compute your function in the shell and then do it in code.

Comment: Very similar question about making sure that fractions are treated as fractions when using sympy: [How to keep fractions in your equation output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651029/how-to-keep-fractions-in-your-equation-output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as others have said, you're not using `Fraction` at all – also, if I understood correctly what your `new_matrix_aux` stuff should do, here's a version that

1. uses proper `Fraction`s
2. substitutes the desired variable values into a series of expressions and sympy-evaluates them:

```
from fractions import Fraction

import sympy as sp


def generate_funcs(function_template, variables):
    variable_names, variable_values = zip(*variables.items())
    for this_values in zip(*variable_values, strict=True):
        replacements = dict(zip(variable_names, this_values))
        func = function_template
        for var, value in replacements.items():
            func = func.replace(var, str(value) if isinstance(value, int) else f"({value})")
        yield func


out_names = ["B", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "U1", "U2"]
vals = {
    "U1": [0] * 8,
    "U2": [0] * 8,
    "X1": [Fraction(4, 3), 1, 0, Fraction(2, 3), Fraction(-2, 3), Fraction(1, 3), Fraction(2, 3), Fraction(-1, 3)],
    "X2": [Fraction(10, 3), 0, 1, Fraction(2, 3), Fraction(1, 3), Fraction(-2, 3), Fraction(-1, 3), Fraction(2, 3)],
    "X3": [0] * 8,
    "X4": [0] * 8,
    "X5": [0] * 8,
}

z_function = "1 * X1 + 2 * X2 + 3 * X3 + 0 * X4 + 0 * X5 + M * U1 + M * U2"

results = {}

for out_name, operation in zip(out_names, generate_funcs(z_function, vals)):
    print(out_name, "=", operation)
    results[out_name] = sp.sympify(operation)

print(results)
```

The output is e.g.

```
B = 1 * (4/3) + 2 * (10/3) + 3 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 0 + M * 0
X1 = 1 * 1 + 2 * 0 + 3 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 0 + M * 0
X2 = 1 * 0 + 2 * 1 + 3 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 0 + M * 0
X3 = 1 * (2/3) + 2 * (2/3) + 3 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 0 + M * 0
X4 = 1 * (-2/3) + 2 * (1/3) + 3 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 0 + M * 0
X5 = 1 * (1/3) + 2 * (-2/3) + 3 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 0 + M * 0
U1 = 1 * (2/3) + 2 * (-1/3) + 3 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 0 + M * 0
U2 = 1 * (-1/3) + 2 * (2/3) + 3 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 0 + M * 0
{'B': 8, 'X1': 1, 'X2': 2, 'X3': 2, 'X4': 0, 'X5': -1, 'U1': 0, 'U2': 1}
```

Comment: I think there is no good reason to mix sympy and fractions.Fraction; instead of `Fraction(2, 3)` you might as well use `sympy.Rational(2,3)` or `sympy.Integer(2) / 3` or `sympy.sympify(2) / 3`

Comment: @Stef Sure, though that might make the whole string substitution thing harder. (Then again, Sympy probably has an API for symbol substitution – would be better to do it at that level...)

Comment: `sympy` `expressions` have a good `subs` method.

Answer (score 5):

Your code begins with `from fractions import Fraction`, but then you never use `Fraction` at all.

To declare a `Fraction` in python, write the word explicitly:

```py
from fractions import Fraction

x = Fraction(1, 3)  # fraction
y = 1/3             # not a fraction

print('x = {}  {}'.format(x, type(x)))
print('y = {}  {}'.format(y, type(y)))
# x = 1/3  <class 'fractions.Fraction'>
# y = 0.3333333333333333  <class 'float'>
```

Alternatively, since you're using `sympy`, you can use `sympy.Rational`:

```py
import sympy

x = sympy.Rational(1,3)
```

If you only need fractions, then use `fractions.Fraction`. But if you need some more stuff from sympy, then I recommend sticking to sympy entirely and using `sympy.Rational`.